# Processing records in select statement

Tags: oracle

I have a table with list of records or cards passing a place

```
ID: int
CarPlate: int
PassDate: date
PassType: byte > 1 enter, 2 exit
```

I want to select the total amount of time each car has been in that place by date
now this is my strategy but I cant implement it.

Imaging in a particular date a cards enters and exits are as followed:

```
    1- enter >
    2- enter >
    3- < exit
    4- enter >
    5- < exit
```

This particular car has entered 3 times and exited two times, I only want the enter and exit that are back to back so I need to select all the enters for all card in a particular date and then for every enter check whether there is a exit before the next enter or not and continue this to the end for each plate and then the next plate.

I have problem implementing this process of going through plates
and at the end for my end result should be something like this

```
CarPlate | Date | EnterExit | Duration
```

This EnterExit is a string of collections of enters and exits

```
    enter at ..... exit at .....
    enter at ..... exit at .....
    enter at ..... exit at .....
    enter at ..... exit at .....
```

Comment: Post some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select carplate,
       enter_time, 
       exit_time, 
       exit_time - enter_time as duration
from (
  select carplate, 
         passtype, 
         passdate,
         case
           when passtype = 'exit' then lag(passdate) over (partition by carplate order by passdate)
           else null
         end as enter_time,
         case 
           when passtype = 'exit' then passdate
           else null
         end as exit_time, 
         case 
            when lag(passtype) over (partition by carplate order by passdate) <> passtype then 1
            else 0
         end as valid
  from cars
  order by carplate, passdate
) t
where valid = 1 
  and passtype = 'exit';
```

(I replaced your values `1` and `2` with `'enter'` and `'exit'` to make the query more readable)

This calculates the enter/exit times for successive rows and then only selects those where an `exit` occurs right after an `enter`.

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df6c0/1